# How to convert a 4-byte "string" to an uint32_t?

Tags: c, binary-data, glib

Basically, I have a byte-string of data like: `\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x08\x00\x00\x00 \x05\x00\x00\x00` (spaces are used only for visibility, there are no space bytes in the actual byte-string). The data is little-endian.

Now, I need to extract the second 4-byte group (`\x08\x00\x00\x00`, which is `128`) and turn them it an unsigned long. So, `uint32_t` type.

Basically, what I'm doing is: `moveBlock(&gdata->str[4], &second_group, 4);`

Where `moveBlock` is a macro: `#define moveBlock(src,dest,size) memmove(dest,src,size)`.
I use the macro because I personally prefer that order of parameters, if someone's wondering.

`gdata->str` is a pointer to a `gchar *`([ref. here](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Basic-Types.html#gchar))
and gdata is a `GString *`([ref. here](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Strings.html#GString)).
`second_group` is defined as an `uint32_t`.

So, this works *sometimes*, but not always. I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks!

---

P.S: The code it a bit lengthy and weird, and I don't think that going through it all would be relevant. Unless someone asks for it, I won't unnecessarily clutter the question

Comment: It works "sometimes"? What happens in the cases where it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you checking to make sure `gdata->len` is `>= 8`?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin that somehow produced `1`.

Comment: Not with the string you posted above it didn't.

Comment: @一二三 Well, it starts spitting out weird numbers. I sort of suspect that it only reads the first byte, maybe? I don't know how to confirm my suspicion, though.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, you mean it doesn't copy the right data?  I doubt that.  Or does that mean you don't see the number you expect?  Maybe you have a wrong offset?  Or wrong expectations? :-)

Comment: @Alok Well, I am certain it's the the second series of four bytes. And I know that it's supposed to be numeric. Not anything else.

Comment: For reference, `\x08\x00\x00\x00` is 8, not 128.  Little-endian affects the order of bytes, but the order of the bits (or nibbles, as you're interpreting it) within the byte doesn't change.

Comment: Any 4 bytes can be interpreted as a `uint32_t` number, so you should always get a numeric answer - and `char` is also an integral type, so the four bytes are also definitely numeric.  So I am not certain what you mean.

Comment: @cHao That's a series of 4 bytes, not bits. So, it's still 128, then. :)

Comment: Is it just me or should this either be ntohl() or htonl()? My head's too fuzzy to say which.

Comment: @withadot.: 128 is represented in little-endian by `\x80 \x00 \x00 \x00`.

Comment: @WarrenP, `htonl` and `ntohl` do the same thing (which can be nothing), so it doesn't matter which you use :-)

Comment: @WarrenP: Neither.  `htonl` and `ntohl` (which would do the same thing on almost all systems, BTW) work when you're working with big-endian, cause that's "network byte order".  But when you're working with little-endian, they don't do what you want -- they're generally no-ops on big-endian systems (since the network order and host order are identical), and on a little-endian system, the bytes already *are* in host order.

Comment: @cHao Isn't that what I typed, though? D:

Comment: @Alok Well, I am so confused now. I will play with it a little more, and update if I find some new information. I can't figure it out for now.

Comment: @withadot.: Nope.  You typed `\08\00\00\00`.  Which is an invalid octal sequence, so i figured you meant `\x08\x00\x00\x00`.

Comment: @cHao Oh! I'll edit that, then.

Comment: By the way, `memmove` is the wrong idiom here. `memcpy` would make sense, but using `memmove` implies you're shifting data within a single buffer rather than copying it to a separate non-overlapping object.

Comment: @R.. Oh, I used memmove because I read somewhere that it's "safer?" I can't recall where, though.

Comment: `memmove` is safe when the source and destination ranges overlap; using `memcpy` in that case invokes UB. But at least the way I see it, using `memmove` also *documents your knowledge* that you're moving data within a single buffer. When I see `memmove`, I expect it to be used for this purpose, and if it's not, I'll probably spend an inordinate amount of time trying to figure out why it was used instead of `memcpy` and if the code was perhaps originally moving data within a single buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the clean portable version:

```
unsigned char *p = (void *)data_source;
uint32_t x = p[0] + 256U*p[1] + 65536U*p[2] + 16777216U*p[3];
```

Comment: You should work with the shifting operator<< instead of multiplying with a high number...

Comment: Because (1) you did do the calculation yourself, (2) shift operations are much faster and most but not least (3) they are much more readable

Comment: @DrumM: (1) These are well-known numbers, not the result of calculation. (2) Neither form is faster or slower. The compiler is free to implement `<<` with a `mul` instruction or `*` with whatever combination of shift and add instructions make sense. (3) Perhaps, but also more work to get right. Since the last shift has to be done as an unsigned one to avoid undefined behavior, an explicit cast or gratuitous arithmetic forcing a promotion would be needed. With the `*`, you can just use an unsigned multiplicand.

Comment: @R, I don't agree with your (1): people can hardly remember 4 numbers, you are remembering 16777216?? Better to use 1 << 7 (because the number in hex is 0x1000000, which is even easier to remember than yours and is also an unsigned value)
You're probably right about being slower or faster, but it's just more readable, generic, usable and adaptable. (3) Fine, but if you use a hex number or a shift, that won't change unsigned to signed either.

Comment: @DrumM: There's no "changing unsigned to signed". In a naive form with shifts or multiplication by signed powers of two, the promoted operands have type `int`. `unsigned char` promotes to `int`, not `unsigned int`, unless `sizeof(int)==1`, in which case lots of things go wrong and you basically can't have a hosted implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`strtoul()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/)

Edit: you will have to null terminate your array to make it a string.

Comment: No. `strtoul` converts nul-terminated string of digits to number.

Comment: Then it isn't a 4-byte "string".

Comment: There were quotations for a reason. :D

Comment: Well you could go with R.. which is a good solution or null terminate and use a standard C function.

Comment: No. He can't nul-terminate and use `strtoul`. His bytes don't contain digits. They contain 8-bit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

the "string" is actually in big endian.

then you need `be32toh` or write it yourself like this:

```
uint32_t conver(const void *src){
   const char *s = src;
   const char out[] = { s[3],s[2],s[1], s[0] };
   return (uint32_t) out;
}
```

Note: I did not tried the code, there might be errors, but you get the idea