# how to convert string to hexadecimal?

Tags: c

I have a string `0xFF`, is there any function like `atoi` which reads that string and save in a `uint32_t` format?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346240/how-to-convert-a-4-byte-string-to-an-uint32-t

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith: No; that's totally different.

Comment: For more information you may want to check out the "Fixed width integer types" section at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Answer (score 5):

you can also do it with a function like this.

```
unsigned int foo(const char * s) {
 unsigned int result = 0;
 int c ;
 if ('0' == *s && 'x' == *(s+1)) { s+=2;
  while (*s) {
   result = result << 4;
   if (c=(*s-'0'),(c>=0 && c <=9)) result|=c;
   else if (c=(*s-'A'),(c>=0 && c <=5)) result|=(c+10);
   else if (c=(*s-'a'),(c>=0 && c <=5)) result|=(c+10);
   else break;
   ++s;
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

example:

```
 printf("%08x\n",foo("0xff"));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *hexValue = "0xFF";
    char *p;
    uint32_t uv=0;
    uv=strtoul(hexValue, &p, 16);
    printf("%u\n", uv);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const char *str = "0xFF";
uint32_t value;
if (1 == sscanf(str, "0x%"SCNx32, &value)) {
    // value now contains the value in the string--decimal 255, in this case.
}
```

Comment: do i need to put SCNx32 in the syntax? do i need to have that if condition? cant i jus use sscanf(str, "0x%x", &value)?

Comment: If you are scanning into a `uint32_t` directly, you *must* use `"%"SCNx32` or you risk undefined behaviour. If you are scanning into an `unsigned int`, you can use `"%x"`. However, for maximum portability, you should use at least an `unsigned long` (scanned with `"%lx"`) since not all systems have 32-bit `unsigned int`s. If you choose that route for whatever reason, you can assign the value of the `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` to your `uint32_t` variable *after `sscanf()` returns*.