# Hexadecimal String Conversion to Integer in C

Tags: c, converters

I have a 4 byte string of hex characters and I want to convert them into a 2 byte integer in c.

I cannot use strtol, fprintf or fscanf.

I want this:-

```
unsigned char *hexstring = "12FF";
```

To be converted to this:-

```
unsigned int hexInt = 0x12FF
```

Comment: Hint : 12FF is  4863, convert hex to integer

Comment: so you want to rewrite C code? Or you have a file that's full of 4byte chars that need to be hexified? Either way... smells like homework.

Comment: obligatory "what have you tried" comment.

Comment: LOL, not homework, I am a 43 years old professional programmer, just getting back into c after a 25 year break. My iPhone app is sending hex characters to my microcontroller, which then needs to be converted into an int to be used in my code. As I am programming a microcontroller, I do not have access to these libraries and I prefer not to add them as it takes up space on my microcontroller's memory.

Comment: What have I tried, I'm actually stumped on this one. All searches suggest strtol, fprintf and fscanf. These are not provided by default with the RTOS I am using, so I will need to get them from somewhere else, but this all leads to extra space being used. Hence me seeking advise from others...even suggestions on techniques to try.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10746672/2598660 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Doh, just read azmuhak's suggested link. This is definitely a duplicate of that question. The answer in azmuhak's link is also more complete because it deals with "0x" prefixes...

The following will work with **out** using the standard library...
See it on [***ideone here***](http://ideone.com/YNNmqa)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ASCII_0_VALU 48
#define ASCII_9_VALU 57
#define ASCII_A_VALU 65
#define ASCII_F_VALU 70

unsigned int HexStringToUInt(char const* hexstring)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    char const *c = hexstring;
    char thisC;

    while( (thisC = *c) != NULL )
    {
        unsigned int add;
        thisC = toupper(thisC);

        result <<= 4;

        if( thisC >= ASCII_0_VALU &&  thisC <= ASCII_9_VALU )
            add = thisC - ASCII_0_VALU;
        else if( thisC >= ASCII_A_VALU && thisC <= ASCII_F_VALU)
            add = thisC - ASCII_A_VALU + 10;
        else
        {
            printf("Unrecognised hex character \"%c\"\n", thisC);
            exit(-1);
        }

        result += add;
        ++c;
    }

    return result;  
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf("\nANSWER(\"12FF\"): %d\n", HexStringToUInt("12FF"));
    printf("\nANSWER(\"abcd\"): %d\n", HexStringToUInt("abcd"));

    return 0;
}
```

The code could be made more efficient and I use the `toupper` library function, but you could easily implement that yourself...

Also, this won't parse strings beginning with "0x"... but you could add a quick check for that at the beginning of the function and just chew up those characters...

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. No need to use toupper, as my app sends all characters in uppercase.

Comment: You would use the ASCII character instead of this integer like `#define ASCII_0_VALU '0'` instead of `#define ASCII_0_VALU 48`. It might be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use strtol() from stdlib.h

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm

```
const char* str = "12FF" ;
long val = strtol(str, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: Except that he specifically says that he can't. Read the question.