# Print the hexadecimal value of package

Tags: c, hex, buffer

I have some ASN.1 encode package.

```
message1->number= clientNumber;
    char    buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    size_t  bufferLen = sizeof(buffer); 
    der_encode_to_buffer(&asn_DEF_Message01, message1, buffer, bufferLen);
```

Is there a function who print the hexadecimal value of the buffer wher the number is encoded ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [`strtoul()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/). With a base-parameter of 16 you can convert your hex-string to a posivite integer.

You can than print your integer with `printf("%x",...)`.

Also see: [how to convert string to hexadecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746450/how-to-convert-string-to-hexadecimal)