# Converting a char* containing hex digits

Tags: c

I invoke the following program with `920173e3` as commandline argument:

```
void getAddr(void* addr)
{
    unsigned const char* temp = (unsigned const char*)addr;
    printf("%s", &temp[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    getAddr(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

`printf("%s", &temp[0])` prints `920173e3` correctly, but how can I then print `920173e4` and `920173e5` and so on?

If I try something like `printf("%s", &temp[1])` or `temp++`, then `printf("%s", &temp[0])` just cuts off parts of the original string (`920173e3` becomes `20173e3`, then `0173e3` and so on).

Comment: So you just want to know how to convert a string to hex? All the rest of your question is just extra detail on why you want to do it? If so, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746450/how-to-convert-string-to-hexadecimal

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to what you aim to do, but you should keep in mind that every process has its own private virtual memory. So running this program with the input `930582ef` will not let you see what's in the physical memory address `930582ef`, rather you will get what the program sees as `930582ef` in its virtual address space, which is likely some other physical address. If the address goes outside the program's private memory you'll get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Are you asking the algorithm to convert hex to decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because it operates on strings instead of numbers.  When you print `&temp[0]` it's the same as printing `temp` directly; when you "increment" it, you're incrementing the pointer to the beginning of the string, so it removes one character from the front.

To actually increment it as a number, you need to convert it to one, and display it as one:

```
void getAddr(unsigned long addr)
{
  printf("%lx", addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  getAddr(strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 16));
  return 0;
}
```

Now you can increment it properly, etc.

Comment: You probably know this. But it is important to check the return value of `strtol` because it can fail.

Comment: @self: yes, I elided error checking because it's a toy program.  Good point though.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Now that we are using long instead of char*, how do I output the bytes at that address though?

Comment: @user3742048: You can cast the `long` to a `char*` and print bytes from there if you want.  Not sure why you'd want to do that though.