# C - Convert const char hex string to unsigned char

Tags: c, arrays, string

I couldent find any working implementations around, so I wrote one using sccanf but I have a problem, Im converting the const char to a unsigned char "FFx16" form, however it converts all characters but the second last character it changes it to "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0F" on the output from printf,  (Ive left the debug funcs in for testing), I know there are c++ versions around but I would prefer pure c, so heres my attempt anyway but still doesent work :(

Code :

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "util.h"
   #include <string.h>

   char* hex_to_char(const char* hex, int len) {
       char *_a = malloc(len / 2);
       int num = 0;
       unsigned _b;
       while(num < len) {
           sscanf(&hex[num], "%02X", &_b);
           _a[num/2] = _b;
           num++;
       }

       return _a;
   }
```

Usage :

```
    const char* buf2 = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
    unsigned char start_seed[16];
    int t = 0;
    char* buf = hex_to_char(buf2, 32);
    if(debug == 1) { printf("Start Seed : "); }
    while(t < 16) {
        start_seed[t] = (unsigned char)buf[t];
        if(debug == 1) { printf("%02X", buf[t]); }
        t++;
    }
    if(debug == 1) { printf("\n"); }
```

// Outputs : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0F

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746450/how-to-convert-string-to-hexadecimal/10746672#10746672

Comment: Use `num += 2` instead of `num++`.

Comment: Thanks Wintermute, sorry tired, probably shouldent be coding xD

Answer (score 0):

Use `num += 2` instead of `num++`.
                    – Wintermute