# Convert char array to hex array

Tags: c, arrays

Input:

```
char arr1[9] = "+100-200"  // (+ is 2B, - is 2D, 1 is 31 and 2 is 32)
```

Output:

```
unsigned int arr2[4]= [0x2B31,0x3030,0x2D32,0x3030]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Very similar to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746450/how-to-convert-string-to-hexadecimal).

Comment: Cast to unsigned char for safety. An unsigned char is a small integer in the range 0-0xFF. Two of them can be combined to mkae a 16-bit integer in the range 0-0xFFFF simply by bit shifting and logical or-ing

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: to accomodate 16-bit ints, it would be safer to cast the result to `(unsigned int)` before shifting.  The specific values in the example would not pose a problem, but the code should be as generic and portable as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems inconsistent: `0` should convert to `0x30`, its ASCII value.

Why this modification, the code is quite straightforward:

```
char arr1[8] = "+100-200";
unsigned int arr2[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2) {
    arr2[i / 2] = ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)arr1[i] << 8) |
                   (unsigned int)(unsigned char)arr1[i + 1];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("0x%04X ", arr2[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Output:

```
0x2B31 0x3030 0x2D32 0x3030
```

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I have edited the original post to make the question clear.